# Analyse JMeter stress test results

Tags: java, elasticsearch, jmeter, stress-testing

I am new to jmeter tool and have created a script for stress testing ElasticSearch server.

I know that this question has been asked here earlier but I am still not able to figure out what is the significance of the different parameters in the Jmeter summary report ?

Here are my JMeter setup:

No. of threads: 4000

Ramp-up period : 5

Loop Count: 1

Results :

Average:108782

Min: 5757

Max: 258917

Throughput: 15.4/sec

Can someone please explain what does each of the terms in the response column of the image below signify. Also, which metric can I use to gauge my server capacity.

[image: Result Summary]

Answer (score 0):

Your "stress test" is not very representative. With regards to what do these metrics mean refer [Summary Report listener documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report) and [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)

1. `# Samples` - how many requests were executed
2. `Average` - [average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean) response time (sum of all response times divided by their count)
3. `Min` - minimum response time
4. `Max` - maximum response time
5. `Std. Dev` - [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) - statistical function showing distribution of response times
6. `Error %` - percentage of failed requests
7. `Throughput` - number of requests per unit of time (second)
8. `Received KB/s` - how many kilobytes per second were received from the server
9. `Sent KB/s` - the same for outgoing requests
   10.`Avg Bytes` - average response size in bytes

Also be informed that most probably you haven't reached concurrency of 4000 users as given you have 1 iteration only it might be the case some virtual users finished their work already and some haven't been started yet.

So I would recommend the following:

1. Setting loop count in [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to `-1` or ticking Forever
2. Setting test duration to i.e. 5 minutes or more
3. [Increasing the load gradually](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-period)
4. When the test finishes generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) and inspect relationship between number of users vs response time vs transactions per second as difference between 5 seconds of minimum response time and 25 seconds of maximum response time looks suspicious and most probably there is a bottleneck somewhere